# Share company local repo in package managers

Tags: cocoapods, bitbucket, carthage

We have a library in a private repo on Bitbucket, that we would like to share among developers internally.

How do you handle this with package package managers like Carthage etc.

In Carthage I have tried something like this:

```
git https://userName@bitbucket.org/company/private-repo.git
```

I am considering sharing a ssh key, what do you thing?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options for Cocoapods.

1. For your pod you can specify git path, like `pod 'PrivatePod', :git => 'https://userName@bitbucket.org/company/private-repo.git'`
2. You can create your private spec repo, and then add `source` string in your `Podfile` before `target` section:

   ```
   source 'https://userName@bitbucket.org/company/private-spec-repo.git'

   target ...
     pod 'PrivatePod'
     ...
   ```

For more info see that link: https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html